# I want to parallelize this code to execute faster for 800000 sentences

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

```
from app import getPhonemes
import pandas as pd
import sys

triphones = []

def phonemize(sentence):

    tokens = sentence.split(' ')
    phonemes = getPhonemes(tokens)
    return '$'.join(phonemes)

def generateTriphones(phonemes):
    triphones = []
    for i in range(len(phonemes)):
        for j in range(len(phonemes)):
            for k in range(len(phonemes)):
                triphones.append(phonemes[i] + ' ' + phonemes[j] + ' ' + phonemes[k])
    return triphones

def scoreSentence(sentence,phonemes):
    flag = 0
    global triphones
    score = 0
    tokens = sentence.split('$')
    uniqueTokens = set(tokens)
    triphoneticTokens = [token for token in uniqueTokens if token.count(' ') > 1]
    for token in triphoneticTokens:
        for triphone in triphones:
            if token.find(triphone) != -1:
                score += 1
                triphones.remove(triphone)
                if triphones == []:
                    flag = -1
    return score, flag

def Process(fil):

    global triphones
    file = open('itudict/vocab.phoneme', 'r',encoding='utf-8')
    data = []
    for line in file:
        data.append(line.strip())
    file.close()
    phonemes = data[4:]
    triphones = generateTriphones(phonemes)

    data = pd.read_csv(fil+'.csv')
    data = data.drop(['score','covered_vocab'],axis=1)

    i = 1
    while len(data) > 0:
        print('Processing File: '+str(i))
        sentencee = data[:10000]
        data = data[10000:]
        sentences = sentencee['sentence'].tolist()
        phonemes = []
        scores = []
        for j in range(len(sentences)):
            if j%1000 == 0:
                print('Processing Sentence: '+str(j))
                print(len(triphones))
            phones = phonemize(sentences[j])
            score, flag = scoreSentence(phones,phonemes)
            if flag == -1:
                data = []
            phonemes.append(phones)
            scores.append(score)
        data['Phonemes'] = phonemes
        data['score'] = scores
        data.to_csv(fil+'phonemized'+str(i)+'.csv', index=False)
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Process(sys.argv[1])
```

I am trying to generate the phonemes for 800000 sentences. The model which am using is G2P which phonemizes the sentence. after phonemization i am calculating the scores. the phoneme array which i am using for calculating scores is of size 2620000.
The length of sentences are 800000 and the code is taking days, can somebody parallelize this code or suggest some solution

I want to parallelize this code to execute faster.

Comment: easiest way to parallelize this is to split up the list into N different lists (where N is the number of processors you have) and simply run N instances of the script. this will require no changes to your code. but you also have numerous operations (such as searching a list) that will get slower the more items you have, so you may have better results using better data structures (such as a set in that case).

Comment: i tried running the multiple scripts but it slows down all the processes.

Comment: Are the files on separate drives? You may be I/O bound here.

Comment: The files are also in same directory

Comment: If I were you I would take a very close look at `scoreSentence` and study it for performance.  You probably want to work on it with a small subset of the total number of sentences.  The `token.find` looks very inefficient; even Pythons `in` operator (`if token in triphone`) would probably be better.  Also, sorting the list of triphones and performing a binary search for matches, instead of a brute force loop through all the elements, might be dramatically better.  Finally, I think you have a bug: triphones.remove will change the same list you are iterating over.